# How to sort an already sorted array by a second property?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Lets say I have a list of tuples, and by calling sort where key = first element, our list comes back as:

`[(1, 'e'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'f')]`

Now, how do I apply a sort that applies only to those values where the first values match, (in this case, the three values that have first element as 3), so that the final list is:

`[(1, 'e'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'f')]`

I have applied a sort to the first element, but when I apply a sort to the second element, the first sort becomes undone. I would like to keep the original sort, and change ONLY those elements with duplicate first elements.

Thank you!

Comment: Tuples already sort this way: have you tried `sorted( [(1, 'e'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'f')])`?

Comment: construct a key from both values in the tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `.sort()` method in Python already does this. For example, the code:

```
L = [(1, 'e'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'f')]
L.sort()

print(L)
```

Returns `[(1, 'e'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'f')]` which is what you want

Comment: Interesting! I recall using this method on a problem a while ago, and it didn't seem to work. I must have messed up somehow. As your answer was first, I will choose your solution. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure I would count on this working in all cases.

Comment: @LhasaDad Tuples and lists in Python compare lexicographically (though by item, not by character as strings do). In all cases. The only way this doesn't do what you want is if you have a value that is not comparable, or if you want a non-default ordering,

Comment: i was expecting it might coerce it to using __str__ or __repr__  good to know though